# binded mesh deform object won't move

Tags: mesh, modifiers, cloth-simulation

[image]

I'm attempting to mesh deform a grid with a thick cloth. I'm doing everything as I usually do it but after binding, the grid perfectly stays in place.
[image: seen here is the cage and the grid]

the grid was created through a boolean difference of an array of cubes.

grid modifier list:

[image: Here is the grid modifier list]

cage modifier list:

[image: and here is the cage modifier list]

thank you so much

Comment: Try it in this order: Unbind the Mesh Deform, disable the Cloth modifier, Bind again, reactivate the Cloth, play. If it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Tried that order and still doesn't work. I added the link to the top of the post for the file. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a *Mesh Deform*, so you need to make sure that the "cage" contains the object, so put it a bit above and give it more thickness with the *Solidify*:

[image]

Also maybe try with a *Surface Deform*, it should work as fine as it's a flat object.